# Android Problem on Widget ImageButton click

Tags: android, click, widget, listener, imagebutton

I'm new in Android development, and my English is awfull.

I have an application with a homescreen widget.

When I start application, in main activity, I can select options for widget (these options are saved to a DB).

Then, I add a Widget, that it have an ImageButton on it, to the homescreen. The click on ImageButton works fine.

If I kill the application activity with some Task Manager, delete the widget, and add it again. The click on ImageButton crash.

Is this normally?

Here you have the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service cat.aat.quoteswidget.Widget$UpdateService@45d1b188 with Intent { cmp=cat.aat.quoteswidget/.Widget$UpdateService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3282)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at cat.aat.quoteswidget.Widget$UpdateService.buildUpdate(Widget.java:130)
at cat.aat.quoteswidget.Widget$UpdateService.onStart(Widget.java:90)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3267)
... 10 more
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 130 of your `Widget.java` file, in the `buildUpdate()` method of your `UpdateService`.

Comment: Yes... Yes... But this same line 130 works fine if Application was not killed with some Task Manager... the question, is if I need to start or instance some thing to do that this works always...
Thanks!

Comment: @aaubets: You need to examine line 130, find what circumstances it might have a `NullPointerException`, and fix your bug. Others might be able to help you with that, but only if you actually provide the source code and indicate the line in question.

Comment: Ok. Later I update the question with de source code... the question, initially, are oriented to if it's a common error, or a concret error in my code. Thanks